# how to resolve conflicting entities of spring-boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

i have a spring-boot project(project1) in which other two spring-boot projects(project2 & project3) are imported as mvn dependency.
project2 and project3 both have entity class with same name ie.entity1 ,  for a same table tbl1.My project project1 has repository class repo1 for entity class of project2.
In My testclass i am using repo1 which supposed to give me object of project2->entity1.At compile time everything seems correct but at the run time the returned object of repo1 is project3->entity1.

jdk12, mvn, spring-boot.
Tried checking linking of my test class with repo1 and entity1 at dry-run time.tried by giving full path of repo1(while autowiring it) and giving full package-path of entity1 in repo1.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to check the import statements of your `project1->repo1` class. In fact, I suppose that `project2->entity1` and `project3->entity1` have different package name.

Comment: yes , project2->entity1 and project3->entity1 both have different package name. imported package in project1->repo1 is project2->entity1.

Comment: even at compile time every object is pointing correct.(command+rightclick taking to the correct entity project2->entity1 in intellij)

Comment: could you please add in your question a minimum code example to reproduce the problem? With the current description, it very difficult to understand what's going on :(